# What is a short history of Ruby on Rails log in system?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, authlogic, restful-authentication

Does any one know of a brief history of Ruby on Rails log in system?  As far as I know, there are 5:

1. write everything yourself (with or without Rails' session)
2. Acts_as_Authenticated written by the same person who wrote Restful Authentication, but is not RESTful.
3. Restful Authentication (also called the AuthenticatedSystem module), which is by `script/generate authenticated user sessions` and the code is mainly in `lib/authenticated_system.rb`
4. AuthLogic
5. Devise

Is this how it evolved -- does anyone know the early history of it -- for example, when Rails first started, was Restful Authentication already there?

Comment: That's pretty much the trends I have noticed too. I have used restful authentication, then authlogic, and now Devise with omniauth :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restful Authentication was the first Rails authentication solution. Its first commit is dated [June 30, 2006](https://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication/graphs/impact). At that time, [Rails 1.0 was already released](https://rubygems.org/gems/rails/versions). Actually, Rails 1.1.4 was released on June 29, 2006.

Restful Authentication was then replaced by Authlogic. The advantages of the latter are that it doesn't create complex scaffold, thus you can easily upgrade the Gem without too much effort.

[Authlogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) has never been updated for Rails 3. Furthermore, Rails 3 is a full Rack stack and Devise is the first authentication system that can handle this kind of architecture.

Almost contemporary of Devise is [Clearance](https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance), the authentication system released by Thoughtbot. It is a Rails 3 engine and it intentionally provide only the basic features of a login system. It was extracted from their app Hoptoad.